# How to update the circular progress button on two view controller? I am using singleton class for circular progress button

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have created the custom circular progress button. Now, I wanted to show it on two view controller with the same progress.

I have created the singleton class so that only a single instance will get updated on both the view controller. Below is singleton class.

```
class DownloadView: UIView 
{

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var circleProgressButton: MyCircularProgressButton!
    @IBOutlet var progressLbl: UILabel!

    static var downloadView = DownloadView()


    func sharedInstance(frame:CGRect)
    {
        self.frame = frame
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit()
    {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DownloadView", owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.fixInView(self)
    }
}

extension UIView
{
    func fixInView(_ container: UIView!) -> Void
    {
            self.frame = container.frame
            container.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

**Actual result** - I am on view controller 1 and it contains the circular progress button, it will start updating the progress status. Now if I move onto the view controller 2, it also contains the circular progress button, it will also start updating the progress. Now if I move from view controller 2 to view controller 1, circular progress button on view controller 1 stop progressing.

**Expected result** - If I move from view controller 1 to view controller 2 or vice versa it should continue updating the circular progress button on both the view controller at the same time.

Comment: you need to call your network api in a separate singleton/shared instance and use that instance to update it.

Comment: @Abu UI Hassan : Thanks for the reply. I understand. but are you sure creating the singleton class of newtwork api will resolve this issue ?

Comment: i have done this with singleton class + delegates  singleton class gets the updates and delegates pass them to delegate owner class like your first and second controllers.

Comment: @Abu UI Hassan: Let me try and i will let you know if i will face any problem. Thank you

Comment: sure, and you welcome.

Comment: @Abu UI Hassan: I have not worked on advance level of singleton class so Please can you share the singleton of network api class. I mean actual code.

Comment: give me a minute.

Comment: Posted complete answer you can Refactor it according to your need :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping me. I gave upvote to both the answers. Now after trying the various ways finally i got how to solve this issue. without singleton, i have solve this issue. I have made DownloadView object static in both the view controller and accessing it from DownloadService class. Now from DownloadService class i am changing the value of progress in both the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's assume you have a code that owns the progress value.

```swift
final class ProgressOwner {
    var progress: Float = 0
    init() {}
}

let progressOwner = ProgressOwner()
```

We need a way to have receive notifications and update the value in your progress view. This could be achieved by using one of the frameworks (`NSNotificationCenter`, `ReactSwift`, `Combine` framework, etc.), or implemented manually like this:

```swift
final class ProgressOwner {
    var progress: Float = 0 {
        didSet {
            observers.forEach { $0(progress) } // When the progress changes we send it to every observer
        }
    }

    private var observers: [(Float) -> ()] = [] // Store all the observers.
    // Note that we store closures, so should be careful with memory management

    init() {}

    func observeProgress(_ callback: @escaping (Float) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {          // Making sure it is the main thread just not to break something in UI
            self.observers.append(callback) // Adding callback as an observer
            callback(self.progress)         // Reporting current progress so that view can update
        }
    }
}
```

What we have left is setup the view in the view controller. Regularly, it is convenient to do in `viewDidLoad` method:

```swift
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let progress: ProgressOwner = ...      /// Need to setup the progress owner that you have
    let progressView = MyCircularProgressButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(progressView)    // Adding progress view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([    // Placing the progress view in the center as an example. We use constraints here, but it can be achieved by setting its frame too
            progressView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            progressView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        // Adding connection to the progress updates
        progress.observeProgress { [weak progressView] progress in
            progressView?.progress = progress // Updating theprogress displayed by the view
        }
    }
}
```

This is it. It is just a generic description of how to solve similar tasks, as I don't know how you name all the classes and variables in your code. You should probably adjust the solution a bit to your code. Regularly we don't apply singleton pattern to views as it can result in pretty hard-debuggable code when a view can accidentally disappear from the screen etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go with all functionality** You may be in need to do some optional chaining so do some effort ;)

```
  protocol DownloadDelegate {
    func updateProgress(updatedProgress:Double)
}
    let AppUtility =  Utility.sharedUtility()
    class Utility: NSObject {
       var progeess:Double = 0.0
        var delegate:DownloadDelegate?
        class func sharedUtility()->Utility!
        {
            struct Static
            {
                static var sharedInstance:Utility?=nil;
                static var onceToken = 0
            }
            Static.sharedInstance = self.init();
            return Static.sharedInstance!
        }
        required override init()
        {

        }
        func netwrokCall(){
            progress = updatedProgress
            delegate.updateProgress(updatedProgress:progress)
    }
    }
  class firstViewController:UIViewController, DownloadDelegate{
       func  viewDidLoad(animated:Bool){
          AppUtility.delegate=self
          AppUtility.networkCall()
      }
    func updateProgress(updatedProgress:Double){
    progressLbl.text = "\(progess)%"
    circleProgressButton.progess = progess
}
    }
     class secondndViewController:UIViewController, DownloadDelegate{
  func  viewDidLoad(animated:Bool){
          AppUtility.delegate=self
      }
     func updateProgress(updatedProgress:Double){
        progressLbl.text = "\(progess)%"
        circleProgressButton.progess = progess
}

    }
```

Comment: @Thank Abu UI Hassan. But in my case i am using URLSession delegate methods. so where i can add those methods.

Comment: In my case, i need to do URLSession singleton right ?

Comment: you can add these method  utility or and call it in networkcall method.

Comment: Okay Abu UI Hassan

Comment: also i have edited extended first and second view controllers with DownloadDelegate make sure to add that.

Comment: No Abu UI Hassan

Comment: update you question with latest code. Including network call.